# Back button throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I have a flow that goes MainActivity -> StoriesActivity -> StoryBodyActivity.

Each passes variables to the next using Intents.

I'm trying to implement a back button from StoryBodyActivity to StoriesActivity, but it's throwing a NullPointerException on `authorID = extras.getInt("author_id");` in StoriesActivity.

I know what a NullPointer is. I just don't know how to fix this one! Could it be because it no longer has access to the data that was passed from the MainActivity?

**Note: This works fine when clicking the back button on the device, just not the icon on the ActionBar.**

Snippet from StoryBodyActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_body);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Snippet from StoriesActivity:

```
private int authorID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stories);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        authorID = extras.getInt("author_id"); // NullPointerException here
        final String authorName = extras.getString("author_name");
        Log.i("click", Integer.toString(authorID));
}
```

Snippet from MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoriesActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("author_id", author.getID());
intent.putExtra("author_name", author.getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Snippet from AndroidManifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".StoriesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".StoryBodyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.apple.bookshelf.StoriesActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.apple.bookshelf.StoriesActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: authorID = extras.getInt("author_id"); from where you send  this value to StoriesActivity:

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya See my update

Comment: thats issue its comes from main activity so after back you have not persistent storage for that value in stories activity

Comment: so use sharedprefrense or some thing like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions here:

First is to check if `extras` exists:

```
if(extras != null){    
    authorID = extras.getInt("author_id"); // NullPointerException here
    final String authorName = extras.getString("author_name");
    Log.i("click", Integer.toString(authorID));
}
```

Second solution is to use `finish()` instead of `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` in StoryBodyActivity.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you! `finish()` was a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is because of the line: 'android:parentActivityName="com.example.apple.bookshelf.StoriesActivity"'

When you are pressing the custom back button, it is creating a new instance of StoriesActivity. I'll suggest to remove:

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.apple.bookshelf.StoriesActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.apple.bookshelf.StoriesActivity" />
```

And replace

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

with

```
onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this you can check if extra exists when coming to this activity.

```
 if (getIntent().hasExtra("author_id")){
        authorID = getIntent().getIntExtra("author_id",0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = getSharedPreferences("alldetais", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPref1.edit();
                      editor1.putString("author_id", author.getID());
                editor1.putString("author_name", author.getName())
    editor1.commit();
```

and get this way

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("alldetais", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        author_id=sharedPref1.getString("author_id","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your code, but I can give an advice, you have to go with the flow of the activities, visualize it as follows, 
Activity A -> activity B -> activity C
So now, if you want to pass data using intent from A to C, then you have to send the data from A to B, then receive it in B, then again pass the received data in from B to C and then use it. Also, i think the more correct way of getting data in B from A will be
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getExtras();